# Convergence of the recursive sequence $(a_n)$ defined by $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{2 + a_n}$, $a_1 = \sqrt{2}$.

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove, directly from the definition of convergence, that the above recursive sequence converges to $2$.

So that we are all on the same page, the definition of convergence given in my class was as follows:

A sequence $(a_n)$ from $\mathbb{R}$ converges to $L \in \mathbb{R}$ if for each $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n \ge N$ then |$a_n - L$|$\le \epsilon$.

In a previous problem I defined $S=\{a_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and proved that $\sup(S)=2$, so I am free to use that result in this proof, but not something like the Monotone Convergence Theorem. There are a number of answers here already that employ this theorem, but I am not looking for that. I need a proof of the convergence of this sequence directly from the definition of convergence.

I am really struggling on what to pick for my big $N$ so that the proof works, mainly since the sequence is defined recursively and not explicitly. Any help would be appreciated!